# Conda not working with XP and Pyrhon 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-xp, conda

I have an installation of Python 2.7 running on an XP machine. The installation was downloaded from Anaconda.  Up until now, I have had no problems with it. I also haven't installed any additional libraries.  I decided I wanted to install
pandas and numpy so I typed

conda install pandas

and got the error message:

The procedure entry poing _snwprintf_s entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

I get the same message when I type

conda help
or
conda

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that conda was updated to use a function that is only available in a newer version of Windows... What is the last version of conda that worked for you? Did you update conda recently?

Comment: This is the only version of conda I have tried on XP. My current installation is the original one so I presumed it was internally consistent. I should add, perhaps, that my installation of XP is inside a Virtual Box virtual machine running under Windows 10. I don't know if that could be part of the problem, but the installation has worked like a charm so far.